# Fixed header hiding content in JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am running jquery-mobile alpha 1 and I am creating a list with a fixed header.  When I view the page the header is on top of the first list item.  The only solution I have found so far is to put a hidden list item with enough space at the top for the header to cover. Is there any other solution?

Here is an initial example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JQuery Mobile List test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a1/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a1/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" data-fullscreen="true" id="list">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>This is a header</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li> <div>Item 1</div> </li>
            <li> <div>Item 2</div> </li>
            <li> <div>Item 3</div> </li>
            <li> <div>Item 4</div> </li>
            <li> <div>Item 5</div> </li>
            <li> <div>Item 6</div> </li>
            <li> <div>Item 7</div> </li> 
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried it with jQueryMobile beta 3?

Answer (score 5):

For the record the problem was that the header had 'data-fullscreen="true".

```
<header data-fullscreen="true>
```

After removing this attribute the list is placed below the header.